# How to access class variable in Python?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python programming and wondering how can I access to variables I have declared in one file to another? I'm working on Django and have two files:

1. forms.py

   ```
   class ContactForm(forms.Form):

       full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
       email = forms.EmailField()
       message = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
   ```
2. views.py

   ```
   from .forms import ContactForm

   def contact(request):

       e = ContactForm()
       toPrint = e.get(email)
       print(toPrint)
   ```

I'm just testing it to print on terminal to help me learn how to access those variables to use them in views.py

Comment: You would just do `e.email` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

in the views you would normally pass in the data that went into the form then you can grab it with cleaned_data like this

```
def contact(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email', '')
            # do something with email here??
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments, this answer does not work in the specific case of django, because of some django-magic. But in general this should be correct.

First of, you should declare the variables in the `__init__` function (the constructor) of the `ContactForm` class. Then you store it under `self`:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        self.email = forms.EmailField()
        self.message = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

In either case (if you keep the code like you have it, or you use the constructor function explicitly), you access the variables simply as

```
e = ContactForm()
to_print = e.email
....
```

Comment: While great advice in general, it doesn't work in this specific case. Django forms use some metaclass magic on form fields, and setting the fields in `__init__` breaks the magic. That same metaclass magic means you can't simply access the fields using e.g. `form.email`.

Comment: @knbk I see. It seemed to me the OP was missing some basics about attribute access, and not something specific to django. I'll edit to make your comment clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
e = ContactForm()
```

If your form is validated, you can access by

```
e.cleaned_data.get('email')
```

Answer (score 0):

Django forms use a so-called metaclass. What this does in this specific case is capture all `Field` instance defined on the form, and put them in a dictionary called `declared_fields`. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4696078832f486ba63f0783a0795294b3d80d862/django/forms/forms.py#L30). You would access the original field as `ContactForm.declared_fields['email']`.

The form makes a copy of `declared_fields` and puts it in the `fields` attribute to allow changes to fields in a single form instance. You would then access the fields as follows:

```
e = ContactForm()
e.fields['email']
```

As said by others, if it weren't for the metaclass, you would just use `ContactForm.email` or `e.email`.